# Why is Ruby on Rails secrets.yml not loading?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I am trying to access my secret keys from the `config/secrets.yml` file.

secrets.yml:

```
development:
  secret_key_base: laksjfla...alskdfjlaksjdflaksd
  other_secret: password
```

Rails Console:

```
$ rails c
> Rails.application.secrets
> => {:secret_key_base=>"laksjfla...alskdfjlaksjdflaksd"}
```

Where is my `other_secret`?!

Comment: try to reload spring server with `bin/spring stop`, so the changes to `secrets.yml` should take effect. then run `rails c` again

Comment: That works! How did you know that would fix it?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I've faced a similar problem once, try to reload spring server with `bin/spring stop`, so the changes to `secrets.yml` should take effect. then run `rails c` again. (posting comment as a answer).

There is an open pull request here - https://github.com/rails/spring/pull/289 - spring does not watch for changes in `secrets.yml` by default. One of the comments says:

> new version of gem (spring) still wasn't released, so you can pull it from
>   github or add Spring.watch "config/secrets.yml" to your
>   config/spring.rb meanwhile