# Rails 4.1 environment variables not reloading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, ruby-on-rails-4, environment-variables

I created an `application.yml` file in the config dir and added some key-value pairs (i.e. `AWS_REGION: us-east-1`). I also added the following to `application.rb` to read the file and update the ENV hash:

```
if Rails.env.development?  
  config.before_configuration do
    env_file = File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'application.yml')
    YAML.load(File.open(env_file)).each do |key, value|
      ENV[key.to_s] = value
    end if File.exists?(env_file)
  end
end
```

Then, if I run `rails c` I can see the ENV variables I set in my `application.yml` file (i.e. `ENV['AWS_REGION']`). However, if I update any of the values or even add a new key-value pair to the file, on the next time I run `rails c` the values aren't updated and the new keys aren't available.

I tried restarting Terminal but it didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you run your YAML through a linter to make sure it's not failing to load? http://www.yamllint.com/

Comment: Is this because of spring ?

Comment: @Valerie I hadn't yet, but just used your link and it passed. Thanks, definitely a cool tool.

Comment: @FrederickCheung I don't know if it's related to Spring. My app is currently using 1.1.3.

Comment: Does running spring stop help?

Comment: Yes! I ran `spring stop` and then fired up the console and it worked! I've never had issues with Spring before...do you know what could be causing the issue?

Comment: @FrederickCheung feel free to add an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the problem that spring caches the state of the app as it starts up - it doesn't know that changes to config/application.yml should result in reloading the app

You can customise how spring watches and reloads your app by creating `config/spring.rb` - it looks like adding something like

```
Spring.watch "config/application.yml"
```

is what you're after

Comment: I had to run `bin/spring stop` to get this to take effect. http://stackoverflow.com/a/26323727/1011746

Answer (score 2):

remove `gem 'spring'` from `Gemfile`

Comment: spring just wasted more time than it could ever save me

Comment: Why it wasted your time? Most of the time it is used just out of the box