# Reload the secrets.yml doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, secret-key

I used [config/secrets.yml](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_1_release_notes.html#config-secrets-yml) in rails application.

I added some api keys. and then run `rails c`, then run the following to get secrets values:

```
Rails.application.secrets
```

But I find the old values in `secrets.yml` file.

**Example:**

My old values in `secrets.yml` was:

```
development:
   secret_key_base: 3b7cd727ee24e8444053437c36cc66c3
   email_password: 'old@password'
```

Then I added the following values to be as the following:

```
development:
   secret_key_base: 3b7cd727ee24e8444053437c36cc66c3
   email_password: 'old@password'
   admin_password: 'admin@password'
```

Then run `Rails.application.secrets`, the output is:

```
{:secret_key_base=>"3b7cd727ee24e8444053437c36cc66c3", :email_password=>"old@password"}
```

Without the attribute `admin_password`.

How can I reload the `secrets.yml` file to update the secrets value ?
or How I update rails application configration to load the `secrets.yml` file when restart server, and rails console ?

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26310407/why-is-ruby-on-rails-secrets-yml-not-loading

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I post this answer depend on @FabKremer comment on question.

To solve this issue.I needed to reload the spring server by the following:

```
bin/spring stop
```

For more details, read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26323727/2791480).

Comment: Thanks! Was about to pull my hair figuring out what I was doing wrong :D